# Stacked SVGs with dynamically changing size (via preserveAspectRatio) is buggy in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

Pretty simple, I have a series of stacked SVG graphs that should fill out to the width of their container (which changes on window resize). Obviously as a graph on top expands, those on bottom should be moved downwards according, and vice versa.

Using viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes (e.g. `<svg viewBox="0 0 400 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinyMin meet">`), this is easily done, and works great on Chrome and Firefox, but fails on all versions of IE (what a surprise).

JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/pvg2a4az/2/

It looks like the SVG's height or position gets fixed such that they graphs never move and aren't allowed to expand past their initial size.

Initially I thought it had to do with containing div's not fitting the height of contents, but putting them all into the same div (or removing the div's altogether in jsfiddle) doesn't change anything.

If I change `meet` to `slice`, the SVG's can expand beyond the initial size, but the positions are still 'fixed' so they just end up overlapping each other.

Comment: Removing the three `preserveAspectRatio="xMinyMin meet"` instances from your jsfiddle demo doesn't affect the output at all on Chrome/Mac or Firefox/Mac. I don't have access to IE at the moment, but does removing that attribute happen to fix things in IE? What is the behavior there without `preserveAspectRatio`?

Comment: Andy - It only centers the images - does not make them responsive.

Comment: I typoed it in the fiddle too ('y' should be capitalized). Yeah it's not necessary in the stripped down fiddle but for the full layout I was working on it sets their position correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Inline SVG's to incorporate the "padding-bottom hack":

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
   style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 92%; height: 1px; overflow: visible">
<!-- SVG content -->
```

Read more: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: Odd, adding it that way to the fiddle isn't working for me but in my actual project adding those styles worked. But that's good enough for me, thanks!

Comment: That is strange since I verified it in a fiddle before posting!

Comment: Oh right, on fiddle it's because meet has to be changed to slice. I just added the styles only at first, my mistake!

Comment: Sweet.  Glad you got it!